# Select integer from text file using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to validate the counts from two sources...

I have a text file (c:\LineCount.txt) that is an extract from another program.
I'd like to make a SQL statement something like this:

```
 SELECT a.Count(*) AS "Table Count",
     b.[result from text file] AS "Extract Count"
 FROM TABLE a,
     FILE b
```

This is using PostgreSQL.
What would be the correct syntax of this statement?
I'd like help in trying to get the syntax of writing this statement working, please.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I believe that you cannot query a flat file.  You must first import it into postgres

Comment: [pg_read_file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) NB: "_Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory can be accessed._"

Comment: what is your file format? For some formats there are fdw providers. For example you can read csv format by file_fdw, which is official postgres extension. See how to use it [here](https://www.depesz.com/2011/03/14/waiting-for-9-1-foreign-data-wrapper/)

Comment: @IldarMusin It is an integer saved into a common text file.